# Why can I not use the Dirac delta function in the classical potential expansion?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, voltage, dirac-delta-distributions

I would like to verify my understanding on why it is that we can represent a charge density $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ as delta functions.

If we start from
$$
\nabla^2V=-4\pi\rho(\mathbf{r})\tag{1}
$$
then we conclude that
$$
V=\frac{1}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}+\Gamma(\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{r}')\tag{2}
$$
where $\nabla^2\Gamma=0$. We then find that [plugging (2) in for (1)]
$$
-4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')=-4\pi\rho(\mathbf{r})
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\rho(\mathbf{r})=\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}').
$$
This result is intuitive to me. The charge density $\rho$ is the charge per unit volume, zero everywhere, but has some value at $\mathbf{r}$. The specific value can be obtained by recognizing that, if $\mathbf{r}$ is the only non-vanishing point, it must have a small volume (as to not interfere with other points). Hence,
$$
\rho(\mathbf{r})=\lim_{\mathrm{volume}\to0}\frac{\mathrm{charge}}{\mathrm{volume}}\to\pm\infty
$$

But how could this be so if
$$
V=\int d^3r'\,\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r})}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}=\int d^3r'\,\frac{\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}\to\pm\infty
$$

What assumptions have I made that are incorrect? (Is it that $\rho(\mathbf{r})$ is only a function of $\mathbf{r}$ and not $\mathbf{r}'$ so in fact $\rho(\mathbf{r})=\delta(\mathbf{r})\neq \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$?)

Comment: Not sure how you conclude (2) from (1)?

Comment: @NDewolf the Laplacian of $1/|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|$ is $-4\pi\delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}')$.

Comment: So you're deriving (equation 4) that $\rho = \delta$ by already assuming it?

Comment: @NDewolf  From (2) and (1) we obtain the third equation and hence the fourth one.

Comment: You can assume (2) and use it with (1) to obtain $\rho(r) = \delta(r-r')$, but you cannot just conclude (2) from (1).

Comment: @NDewolf I see. My mistake. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential $V_0(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') = \frac{1}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}'|}$ is a solution to (1) only if $\rho_0(\textbf{r}.\textbf{r}') = \delta(\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}')$ for some *fixed* $\mathbf{r}'$. Also note that $\nabla^2$ acts with respect to the *unprimed* coordinates only.

Because the equation is linear, we can use this to construct a general solution to an arbitrary charge distribution $\rho(\textbf{r})$ (which now is a given function, and not a Dirac delta).
First, we multiply the equation by $\rho(\textbf{r}')$. Here $\textbf{r}'$ is fixed, so $\rho(\textbf{r}')$ is just a number. This yields
\begin{equation}
    \rho(\textbf{r}') \nabla^2 V_0(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') = - \rho(\textbf{r}') 4\pi \delta(\textbf{r} - \textbf{r}').
\end{equation}
Now integrate both sides of the equation with respect to the *primed* coordinates over all of space.
This gives
\begin{equation}
    \int d\textbf{r}' \rho(\textbf{r}') \nabla^2 V_0(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') = -4\pi \int d\textbf{r}' \rho(\textbf{r}') \delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}') = - 4\pi \rho(\textbf{r}).
\end{equation}
Now on the left-hand side of the equation, we note that the integral is with respect to the *primed* coordinates while the differential operator $\nabla^2$ acts with respect to the *unprimed* coordinates. These are independent, so we can move the Laplacian outside the integral. Then we obtain
\begin{equation}
    \nabla^2 \int d\textbf{r}' \rho(\textbf{r}') V_0(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') = -4\pi \rho (\textbf{r})
\end{equation}
But this means that the function
\begin{equation}
    V(\textbf{r}) = \int d\textbf{r}' \rho(\textbf{r}') V_0(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}') 
\end{equation}
solves the equation $\nabla^2 V(\textbf{r}) = - 4\pi \rho(\textbf{r})$. This is the origin of the integral formula that you have at the end.

Comment: Please don't use MathJax for formatting of text (such as `\textit`) -- use the Markdown constructs (like `*italics*` or `_italics_`) instead.

Comment: I've edited in some examples